# Raspberry pi, streamer + crontab + dropbox = catCamera, does not work!

Tags: camera, script, cron, bash

I wrote a bash script that uses the dropbox app as per [RaspiTV](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-dropbox-with-raspberry-pi).  I am using a standard USB webcam and streamer to capture **videos of my cat** when I am away from home with the hope that these can be uploaded to my dropbox account.

the script that does this and **works just fine when run manually** is:

```
#!/bin/bash
streamer -t 0:0:15 -c /dev/video0 -f rgb24 -r 3 -o /home/pi/Downloads/$(date +%m%d_%H%M%S).avi
#echo
fn=`echo $(ls *.avi -t | head -n1)`
echo $fn
/home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/./dropbox_uploader.sh upload $fn /catcamFolder
```

Where `catcamFolder` is my folder on Dropbox where the .avi files are deposited.

When I run my script manually from command line such as: `./myscript.sh`, it runs beautifully and I have the video file depo'd in my dropbox.

However, when I try to cron it using the following `crontab -e` script, nothing happens, the file is neither generated not deposited in dropbox:

```
1,15,30,34,45 7-21 * * * /home/pi/Downloads/myscript.sh
```

So... this crontab line runs `myscript.sh` at minute 1,15,34,45 from 7am-9pm every day.

What am I doing wrong that the script doesn't run through cron but runs fine by itself?  I hope I get help so that I can keep an eye on my feline friend!

By the way, the line of bash script: fn=`echo $(ls *.avi -t | head -n1)` provides the name of the most recent .avi file.  This bit of useful information was from [another SE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1015678/957560)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following call contains a relative path `*`:

```
fn=`echo $(ls *.avi -t | head -n1)`
```

Use absolute paths:

```
fn=`echo $(ls /home/pi/Downloads/*.avi -t | head -n1)`
```

The script will not work even interactively if your current directory is not `/home/pi/Downloads`.

---

Other remarks:

- in this case the above will work, but generally you shouldn't parse the output of `ls` at all ([read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/133107)).
- if you decide to parse `ls` you should at least quote `fn` variable in the call:

  ```
  /home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/./dropbox_uploader.sh upload "$fn" /catcamFolder
  ```

  Again: it's not a direct reason for the problem, but the script will break if files contained spaces.
- `echo` is superfluous in the following assignment:

  ```
  fn=`echo $(ls *.avi -t | head -n1)`
  ```

  It is the same as:

  ```
  fn=$(ls *.avi -t | head -n1)
  ```

Comment: Current directory is /home/pi/downloads.  i.e. the videos are created in /home/pi/downloads and uploaded from here.  Is that not what it is? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, current directory for the script executed by cron is not what you claim.

Comment: I apologize but I have am slow so it is a little tough for me to understand multiple dependencies.  You mean that the `dropbox_uploader.sh` script should be in the current directory?  Again, thank you for your input.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your answer and subsequent edits.  I'll try it out now and see how things go.